# Small number in 4th root

Tags: typography

When running this code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{minionpro,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt[4]{\frac{q_\text{sol} \, \cos\theta}{\sigma}}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Latex produces really ugly result - number 4 is obviously too small.

Any idea how to make it more appealing?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't appear to have easy access to the `minionpro` package, so my answer has to make do with the default font family, Computer Modern.

While the size of the number `4` in the optional argument of the expression `\sqrt[4]{3}` is fine, it does tend to look a tad small if the mandatory argument of `\sqrt` is itselft quite large, as is the case in the fraction expression used by the OP.

By default, the optional argument of `\sqrt` is processed in `\scriptscriptstyle`, for a roughly 50% linear reduction in font size. As the following screenshot shows, you may get a better-looking result if you replace `[4]` with `[\scriptstyle 4]`, for a more moderate 30% linear reduction in font size. (The result of `[\textstyle 4]` looks too large, for sure.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\blurb}{\frac{q_\mathrm{sol} \cos\theta}{\sigma}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt[4]{3} \quad
\sqrt[4]{\blurb} \quad
\sqrt[\scriptscriptstyle 4]{\blurb} \quad
\sqrt[\scriptstyle 4]{\blurb} \quad
\sqrt[\textstyle 4]{\blurb}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the math font size commands in the `\sqrt` optional argument. For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{minionpro}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt[4]{\frac{q_\text{sol} \, \cos\theta}{\sigma}}.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt[\scriptstyle4]{\frac{q_\text{sol} \, \cos\theta}{\sigma}}.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt[\textstyle4]{\frac{q_\text{sol} \, \cos\theta}{\sigma}}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This probably works for `minionpro` as well, but I can't test that because I don't have that font.

Answer (score 2):

From art we know that context matters when anticipating "size". So here are some alternative representations of the 4th root:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}

%\usepackage{minionpro,amsmath}% <<< didn't check for minionpro
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt[4]{\frac{q_\text{sol} \, \cos\theta}{\sigma}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    {\frac{q_\text{sol} \, \cos\theta}{\sigma}}^\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    {(\frac{q_\text{sol} \, \cos\theta}{\sigma})}^\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```